# OptaPlanner's score calculator callbacks for entities

Tags: java, optimization, optaplanner

My model supports real-time change by `Solver#addProblemFactChange` and `ProblemFactChange` interface. Implementing `doChange` method of this interface, I actively use notifications of `scoreDirector` by methods like `beforeEntityRemoved`, `beforeProblemFactRemoved`, `beforeProblemFactChanged` and other. Besides, incremental score calculator of model implements callback methods `beforeEntityAdded`, `beforeEntityRemoved` and their `after`-versions.

Investigating solver behavior, I saw such diagram of score calculator calls from optaplanner:

[image: Callbacks call diagram]

That is optaplanner doesn't invoke entities related methods of calculator despite model changes. Why so occurs and why necessary to notify `scoreDirector`?

Comment: That diagram doesn't look right... or I am intepreting/parsing it incorrectly. Standardizing on an UML sequence diagram should remove my parsing issues.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Yes, my diagram isn't canonical. I use it only to show absence of some callbacks. Correct sequence diagram already exist [in docs](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/images/Chapter-Score_calculation/incrementalScoreCalculatorSequenceDiagram.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProblemFactChange` api has been designed to allow incremental changes to the problem, therefore you need to call `before|afterProblemFactAdded|Changed|Removed()`, otherwise implementing incremental problem changes with be impossible (without changing the API).

It's the `ScoreDirector`'s responsibility to handle those events:

- `DroolsScoreDirector` works incrementally for problem facts too (not just planning variables).
- `IncrementalScoreDirector` does not do it incrementally yet for problem facts (but it does for planning variables). There is just [some stopgap code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/score/director/incremental/IncrementalScoreDirector.java#L123) with a TODO there in 6.2, which works but doesn't work as fast as it should.

[I created a jira issue to track this issue.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-330)